# MVC6 general exception handling to show custom 500 error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a sample code,

```
// EmpInfo.cs
try{
    EmpData empData = readFromDB(empID);
}catch (Exception){
    Logger.logError(“Fails to get data for empID: {0}”, empID);
    throw;
}
```

How do I write the below function to handle the exception in EmpInfo.cs and show the custom 500 error page.
Since I am using MVC6, it has the bulletin OnActionExecuted function to handle the general error. 
Please provide the concrete codes. Thanks!

```
//ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleWare>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        try {
            await this.next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // How to use OnActionExecuted here????????
         }
    }
```

}